# ¿Como puedo hacer que multiples divs funcionen en estado roll over-out con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, funciones

Buenas, necesito saber como hacer este código Java Script más optimizado, me funciona hasta el momento. Tengo Divs con clase "item" e imágenes en su interior. Lo unico que hago es cambiarles el atributo cuando están en mouse over y out, pero necesito ayuda para saber como hacerlo optimo. Muchas gracias.
Tengo este código HTML:

```
<div class="item1">
   <img id="im1" src="img/image1.png">
</div>

<div class="item2">
   <img id="im2" src="img/image2.png">
</div>

<div class="item3">
   <img id="im3" src="img/image3.png">
</div>

<div class="item4">
   <img id="im4" src="img/image4.png">
</div>
```

Y tengo este código Java Script

```
$("#item1").mouseover(function(){
    $('#im1').attr("src", "img/image1_over.png");
});

$("#item1").mouseout(function(){
   $('#im1').attr("src", "img/image1.png");
});

$("#item2").mouseover(function(){
    $('#im2').attr("src", "img/image2_over.png");
});

$("#item2").mouseout(function(){
   $('#im2').attr("src", "img/image2.png");
});

$("#item3").mouseover(function(){
    $('#im3').attr("src", "img/image3_over.png");
});

$("#item3").mouseout(function(){
   $('#im3').attr("src", "img/image3.png");
});

$("#item4").mouseover(function(){
    $('#im4').attr("src", "img/image4_over.png");
});

$("#item4").mouseout(function(){
   $('#im4').attr("src", "img/image4.png");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Si conoces el conteo total de los elementos puedes hacer lo siguiente

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let images = {
    normal: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg',
    over: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg'
  };

  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    const div = $('.item' + i);
    const img = $('#im' + i);
    div.mouseover(function() {
      img.attr("src", images.over);
    });

    div.mouseout(function() {
      img.attr("src", images.normal);
    });
  }

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <img id="im1" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item2">
  <img id="im2" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item3">
  <img id="im3" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item4">
  <img id="im4" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Si no conoces el conteo total de elementos puedes hacer un `each` pero deberás contener los elementos en un `div` padre, ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let images = {
    normal: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg',
    over: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg'
  };

  $('div[class^=item]').each(function(i, e) {
    const div = $(this);
    const img = $(this).find('img');
    div.mouseover(function() {
      img.attr("src", images.over);
    });

    div.mouseout(function() {
      img.attr("src", images.normal);
    });
  })

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <img id="im1" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item2">
  <img id="im2" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item3">
  <img id="im3" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item4">
  <img id="im4" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item5">
  <img id="im5" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>

<div class="item6">
  <img id="im6" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta espectacular, pero faltaría sugerir que el usuario mantenga las url (normal y over) en un arreglo, de tal manera de setear el atributo src acorde al arreglo y no en duro

Comment: @amenadiel Tienes razón, he actualizado mi respuesta, me pareció mejor usar un objeto que un array, jeje

Comment: @Jorius de verdad muchas gracias por tu aporte ya he salido de duda. Saludos

Comment: @AndrésFabiánPaipaCamargo si mi respuesta te ha sido útil por favor marcala como correcta, nos beneficiamos los dos :D